# epoll() waits for full timeout

Tags: python, epoll

I have a Python application that uses `epoll()` to wait for a child process to write to its standard streams. The application is working and Python application is getting data from the child processes in this way. However, I'm often noticing that the whole thing takes *exactly* 1 minute, which makes me think that `epoll()` is not always unblocking as soon as an event occurs. Rather, it seems to be waiting for the entire timeout to expire.

Everything I'm reading tells me the timeout argument shouldn't work this way. What am I doing wrong?

```
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        popen_list,
        bufsize=4096,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        close_fds=True,
    )

    EPOLL_TIMEOUT = 60000; # 1 min
    ep = epoll(2)
    ep.register(process.stdout.fileno())
    ep.register(process.stderr.fileno())

    try:
        while True:
            events = ep.poll(EPOLL_TIMEOUT)

            # If the process is dead, no need to check for events.
            return_value = self.poll()
            if return_value is not None:
                # Process has terminated
                clean_up_epoll(ep)
                handle_terminated_process(return_value)
                break

            for fd, _event_type in events:
                if fd == self._process.stdout.fileno():
                    stdout = _read_from_file(process.stdout)
                    if len(stdout) > 0:
                        _on_read(stdout)
                elif fd == process.stderr.fileno():
                    _handle_stderr()
    finally:
        self._clean_up_epoll(ep)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: the process object was created by ```subprocess.Popen``` and the stdout/stderr pipes were created by passing the ```subprocess.PIPE``` parameter, right? Because if you created the pipe manually and kept the writing side open in the parent process, that would explain why epoll continues to wait for input even after the child's death.

Comment: Exactly. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: the timeout parameter is in seconds, not milliseconds. Not sure if it's relevant.